# Format field for 3 numerical digits with optional letter

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013, dataformat

I have a very large list of assets all with room numbers.  All room number are 3 digits.  Room number on the bottom floor begin with leading zeros (001, 002, etc).  However, some rooms have letters after them (020A, 020B).

How can I format my field in Microsoft Access to display leading zeros but also accept that some rooms have a letter after the 3 digits?

Answer (score 0):

A `text` formatted field will display any entered data as a string literal, i.e. no matter what combination of numbers and letters you enter it will keep those data as typed.  So `001` and `020A` would both be accepted.

Comment: So there is no way to force a format on alphanumeric text?  Whenever I import a spreadsheet (Copy/paste) which has the format required, it always takes it as numbers (make the field integer) and then strips the leading zeros away, as well as ignore room numbers with letters in them...

Comment: @Dorian are you literally copy/pasting from a spreadsheet? Doing that creates all sorts of problems.  If that's the case switch to the External Data Access functions.

Comment: Yes, that's my only option with our workstations, and that's how I receive the data (Excel Spreadsheets). Even when using External Data > Import Excel, it will keep the letters after the number if I specify the field as text, but it still strips the leading zeros.